# k8s Anonymous Access

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, anonymous

We are pretty new to k8s and test out many cloud offerings. I have personally noticed that most cloud vendors allow anonymous access by default to some endpoints. Do you think we should disable it? We had deployed many clusters already, so it can get tedious.

For example: https://34.69.161.57/version

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdEy3.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think we should disable it?

Your question is very general, so it would be easier to answer if some specifics were given... but in general, **it is a good approach to disable all access by default and enable only what is necessary** (not the other way)